# Load Factor from max demand/time graph

Tags: load

[image: Question]

I know Load factor is average demand/max demand so is this then

LF= ((20x4)+(40x4)+(70x8)+(60x4)+(50x4))/70x24

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please click the edit link below your question and add the LF formula.  Please explain why most terms are multiplied by 4 (except one term by 8), and why the average is being divided by 70x24.  Thank you.

Comment: If the max is 70MW, then your LF calc is correct.

Comment: the 4 and 8 come from how long it is on each one.... im unsure what max is but from graph i only goes to 70